# Combination of INNER JOIN and SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table `transactions` with reported financial transactions where both sides of a transaction report (`TRNS_ID` is transaction id, `RA_ID` is reporting agent id, `CNTP_ID` is counterparty id)

```
ID, RA_ID, CNTP_ID, FIELD1, FIELD2
1        A      B        0.1     0.1    
2        B      A        0.1     0.1
---------------------------------------
3        A      B        0.1     0.1    
4        B      A        0.1     0.1
---------------------------------------
5        B      C        0.1     0.1
6        C      B        0.1     0.1
```

Thus, for each transaction taking place between two agents, I have one redundant record and I want to get rid of it (for exposition purposes, I separated transactions belonging together by lines). The problem is to identify both transactions out of many records, possibly involving the same agents.

To do so, I perform a self join to match transactions with each other using `INNER JOIN` and a couple of criteria based on `FIELD1` on `FIELD2`. However, the information may not be enough for a perfect match (see first four records). Hence, I want to match on another field: the reported underlying collateral (possibly multiple items). Reported collaterals are stored in table `collaterals` where `TRNS_ID` is the foreign key

```
ID, COLL, TRNS_ID
1   F     1
2   G     1
3   G     2
4   F     2
-----------
5   H     3
6   H     4
-----------
7   I     5
8   I     6
```

Question: **How can I impose the condition that the collateral items reported by both sides of the transaction are identical in the INNER JOIN query?**

My desired result is

```
RA_TRNS_ID, RA_ID, CNTP_ID, CNTP_TRNS_ID, FIELD1, FIELD2
1           A      B        2             0.1     0.1
3           B      C        4             0.1     0.1
5           B      C        6             0.1     0.1
```

My curret attempt only `INNER JOIN`s on `FIELD1` and `FIELD2`, however this is an imperfect matching because I cannot differentiate between the first two groups of transactions.

```
SELECT 
    x.`TRNS_ID` AS x.`RA_TRNS_ID`, 
    y.`TRNS_ID` AS y.`CNTP_TRNS_ID`, 
    x.`FIELD1` as `RA_FIELD1`,
    y.`FIELD1` as `CNTP_FIELD1`,
    x.`FIELD2` as `RA_FIELD2`,
    y.`FIELD2` as `CNTP_FIELD2`
FROM transactions x
INNER JOIN transactions y
ON x.`CNTP_ID` = y.`RA_ID` AND x.`FIELD1` = y.`FIELD1` AND x.`FIELD2` = y.`FIELD2`
GROUP BY `RA_FIELD1`, `CNTP_FIELD1`, `RA_FIELD2`, `CNTP_FIELD2`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AND` keyword should be in `WHERE` clauses instead of after `ON` keyword.

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions x
INNER JOIN transactions y
ON x.`CNTP_ID` = y.`RA_ID` 
WHERE (SELECT COLL FROM collaterals WHERE TRNS_ID = x.`ID`) = (SELECT COLL FROM collaterals WHERE TRNS_ID = y.`ID`)
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Would I have to incorporate an `ORDER BY COLL ASC` in both `SELECT` to allow for the comparison? Note the ordering in table `TRNS_ID`...

Comment: @Jhonny I think if you use Gordon Linoff's solution, you can easily `ORDER BY cx.COLL`

Comment: I had to create an index on the foreign key to get decent performance. It is working as expected now. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple joins:

```
SELECT tx.*, ty.*
FROM transactions tx JOIN
     collaterals cx
     ON cx.trns_id = tx.id JOIN
     transactions ty
     ON tx.`CNTP_ID` = ty.`RA_ID` JOIN
     collaterals cy
     ON cy.trns_id = ty.id AND cy.COLL = cx.COLL;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon. Do I understand the query correctly when I expect that the result with have as many rows for a single transaction as collateral items are used? Another problem I did not explain is that I can have wrong reportings, i.e. reporting agent with `RA_ID=B` reports only one collateral item. In this case I do not want to match them. Right now I don't see how to accommodate that.

Comment: @Jhonny . . . You may need to ask another question, with a focus on sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you do and do not want.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I did edit my post to explain what I expect. However, my question remains the same and I believe your answer does not satisfy what I am looking for? *How can I self-join the transactions based on the items stored in table `collaterals` and referenced via foreign key `TRNS_ID`?*

Comment: @Jhonny . . . That is what this query does.  The expression `cy.COLL = cx.COLL` does the matching you are asking for.

Comment: I just verified my comment above that I will get as many replications of the transaction as I have underlying collaterals: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da532d/1 This is not what I was hoping for.

Comment: @Jhonny . . . Your original code had comparisons of scalar subqueries (`(SELECT COLL FROM collaterals WHERE ID = x.`ID`)`), strongly implying that there is only one collateral per transaction.

Comment: Sorry that I was not precise enough.